# How to force dispatcher cache urls with get parameters

Tags: apache, caching, aem, dispatcher

As I understood after reading these links:

[How to find out what does dispatcher cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27248505/how-to-find-out-what-does-dispatcher-cache)

http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher.html

```
The Dispatcher always requests the document directly from the AEM instance in the following cases:

If the HTTP method is not GET. Other common methods are POST for form data and HEAD for the HTTP header.
If the request URI contains a question mark "?". This usually indicates a dynamic page, such as a search result, which does not need to be cached.
The file extension is missing. The web server needs the extension to determine the document type (the MIME-type).
The authentication header is set (this can be configured)
```

But I want to cache url with parameters.

If I once request `myUrl/?p1=1&p2=2&p3=3`

then next request to `myUrl/?p1=1&p2=2&p3=3` must be served from dispatcher cache, but `myUrl/?p1=1&p2=2&p3=3&newParam=newValue` should served by CQ for the first time and from dispatcher cache for subsequent requests.

Answer (score 3):

I think the config `/ignoreUrlParams` is what you are looking for. It can be used to white list the query parameters which are used to determine whether a page is cached / delivered from cache or not.

Check http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/disp-config.html#Ignoring%20URL%20Parameters for details.

Comment: I think that at this case for **site.com/page?q=1** and **site.com/page?q=2** dispatcher return same value

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to cache the requests that contain query string. Such calls are considered dynamic therefore it should not be expected to cache them.

On the other hand, if you are certain that such request should be cached cause your application/feature is query driven you can work on it this way.

1. Add Apache rewrite rule that will move the query string of given parameter to selector
2. (optional) Add a CQ filter that will recognize the selector and move it back to query string

The selector can be constructed in a way: `key_value` but that puts some constraints on what could be passed here.

Comment: could you provide example?

Comment: I think the suffix would be a better choice.

Comment: @Tomek Rękawek can you provide more details?  if I change URL - then this url will request another resource. can you explain hoe to resolve this problem?

Comment: https://forums.adobe.com/message/4930557#4930557   Does this topic relevant for me?

Comment: will **myurl.jsp/parameter/values** cache on dispatcher ?

Comment: "_Such calls are considered dynamic therefore it should not be expected to cache them._"

It's entirely fair to expect to be able to cache requests with query parameters - browsers, CDNs, edge side caches all do it fine.

I imagine the actual reason is that the dispatcher's caching is just based on static files on disk, and making the query params part of the filename on disk is awkward. The same reason it can't cache response headers.

Comment: You are right, there are ways to cache dynamic data and they also exist in AEM world. I do not agree the root cause of dispatcher not caching query params is the technical limitation of static file naming. Query params are heavily overused in web world. I believe this is a rational decision not to cache query params to ensure (or even enforce) better application architecture i.e. more aligned to Apache Sling principles.
As per headers - starting from dispatcher 4.1.11 it's actually feasible. See https://www.cognifide.com/our-blogs/cq/aem-dispatcher-new-features

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Apache rewrites BUT it would not be ideal practice.  You'll be breaking the pattern that AEM uses.

Instead, use selectors and extensions.  E.g. instead of server.com/mypage.html?somevalue=true, use:
server.com/mypage.myvalue-true.html

Most things you will need to do that would ever get cached will work this way just fine.  If you give me more details about your requirements and what you are trying to achieve, I can help you perfect the solution.

Comment: will **myurl.jsp/parameter/values** cache on dispatcher ?

Comment: yes.  provided two things: you don't add a query string AND you are always hitting that path with a GET request.  Dispatcher doesn't cache things that have a query string (like you used before) or anything that isn't GET, so POST requests, HEAD requests, etc, get forwarded to CQ/AEM

Comment: @gstackoverflow I just saw the myurl.jsp - this is wrong. It should be myurl.html

Look at how sling selects the script to run.  Chances are you want .html as your extension, unless you want the output in some other format (json) and you have a json.jsp script in your components.