# How to configure both dispatcher & mod_cache on apache webserver ?

Tags: apache, http-caching, mod-cache

I'm using AEM as wcm and lucid as a search. both are hosted on my local machine.
On my local apache webserver, i want to use dispathcer and mod_cache to cache the response.
dispatcher to cache AEM pages and mod_cache to cache the search response which would be in form of json.
dispathcer is working fine and caching the html,js,css. To cache the search results i have configured the mod_cache.
below is configuration:-
i have enabled the LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so in httpd.conf

```
Include conf/dispatcher.conf
Include conf/mod_disk_cache.conf
```

and created a file `mod_disk_cache.conf` where configuration is

```
    <IfModule mod_cache.c>
        <IfModule mod_disk_cache.c>
            CacheRoot "C:/Apache2/cachedoc"
            CacheEnable disk www.local.search.com:8764
            CacheDirLevels 5
            CacheDirLength 3
        </IfModule>
        CacheDisable http://security.update.server/update-list/
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost 10.207.12.34:8764>
    ServerName www.local.search.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache2/htdocs"
</VirtualHost>
```

Still i'm not able to cache the json response of search results. Can anyone help

Comment: Does it work if you disable dispatcher?  Ideally you shouldn't need mod_cache because latest dispatcher supports whitelisting which is similar to vary by params in mod_cache.

Comment: using new dispathcer can i cache the response from third party server(apart from aem) ?

Comment: yes you can. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27290738/how-to-force-dispatcher-cache-urls-with-get-parameters

Comment: but problem is my search requets are not going through cq. there are two separate app server one is cq another is search. request related to cq will cahce through dispathcer but i'm not able to cache the search request on my webserver