# Does file extension is same as url extension in Sling

Tags: caching, aem, dispatcher, sling

Url in `Sling` has following structure:[image]

Also I have read following [information aboutn dispatcher cache](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher.html):

```
The Dispatcher always requests the document directly from the AEM instance in the following cases:

If the HTTP method is not GET. Other common methods are POST for form data and HEAD for the HTTP header.
If the request URI contains a question mark "?". This usually indicates a dynamic page, such as a search result, which does not need to be cached.
The file extension is missing. The web server needs the extension to determine the document type (the MIME-type).
The authentication header is set (this can be configured)
```

**I have 2 misunderstandings:**

1. Will `myurl.com/foo.jsp/parameter/values` comply with following rules:

   The file extension is missing. The web server needs the extension to determine the document type (the MIME-type).

?

2. formulation **Dispatcher always requests the document directly from the AEM instance** doesn't guarantee that in the rest situations request will be cached but I want to be sure that my request will be cached.

### P.S

Please provide concrete steps from the begining how to check that concrete url cashes or not.

Comment: the cheatsheet you provided is not Sling's structure. It simply explains how Sling decides which script is used to render a specific request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That Cheatsheet merely describes how a script is selected to render a specific request. It has no relation with the Apache Dispatcher.

As I answered [in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27248505/how-to-find-out-what-does-dispatcher-cache) what the dispatcher caches or not caches is defined by the rules you set (except for the mentioned exceptions).

The steps to check if a particularly request will be cached is take that request and compare it against each one of the dispatcher rules. The last matching rule is applied.

resourceTypes and other sling concepts are irrelevant here. Only the url string is checked. Your example url has no extension so it wont be cached.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using foo.jsp, you should be using foo.html or whatever your desired format is.

The "suffix" in sling is the part you are talking aobut the /parameter/whatever after the .html

From my understanding and the docs, this should be cached by dispatcher provided there is no query string.